# Why jquery not working on this page but it works on other Normal pages

Tags: html, append, contains

I have this jquery that can detect the sentence and add the span on it

https://cognitive-assessment.iwi.unisg.dev/submission/?mode=preview&token=c5e77101c559cd672654248f52d5692a

this is the page where i want to run jquery

you have to login to view the page

Username:ABC
paswword:ABC@@99

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  
$("h5:contains('Medium Overall Feasibility of Use Case')").html(function(_, html) {
   return html.replace(/(Medium Overall Feasibility of Use Case)/g, '<yellow class="yellow">$1</yellow>');
});

});
```

This is the jQuery that need to run...

Comment: The jQuery snippet you are posting is working on my side (using Chrome v.101).
Is there any specific error you are encountering ?

Comment: Yes it works on my side too... but on these pages it not work  https://cognitive-assessment.iwi.unisg.dev/submission/?mode=preview&token=c5e77101c559cd672654248f52d5692a

Comment: you have to login to see the page i mention the login details in question

Comment: These pages are wpe form submission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery snippet you shared works on my side for the page you shared. As a proof of concept, take a look at the following screenshot:

[image]

What are the other pages you are referring to ?
What exactly doesn't work when you run this code at your side ?

**Note:** It's always a bad idea to publicly share the credentials of your university account, for security reasons.

Comment: It is a subscriber account

Comment: Did you check the Console... There is an error related to js... may be that's why jquery not work on these pages...

Comment: You ask me what kind of pages it is.... it is submission page like a preview of a form.... As i said jquery is working on whole website excerpt of these pages... please check the console...